# creating event in embedded google calendar

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am working on a google app engine based webapp where the user is logged through its Google account. 
Through the Google Api Client library (Python) I retrieve the list of its calendars and display the first by means of an iFrame.

```
     <iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src={{calendar}}" style="border: 0; margin-top:20px"  width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The problem is that it seems the calendar is only displayed and there is no way to create new events.
I know I may create a dialog to add events and rely aganin on the api client library but it would be more intuitive to do that from the displayed calendar. 
is there any way to do that?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?